# Call stored procedure (firebird database) with php PDO

Tags: php, stored-procedures, pdo, firebird

I have some stored procedures on a firebird database.
Now I want to call them with PHP.

SP have a suspend code and a return value and the SP need some input parameters.. 
Can someone help me...

Comment: Have you tried anything specific?

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php
Example 5.....

but that doesn't work... I have 4 input parameters and 1 result.. I don't know how to handle that...

Comment: The link you provided points at examples that _do work_. My question was about _your *specific* attempt_. And please elaborate on _"but that doesn't work"_. All this, by editing your question, _not_ in comments.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Firebird doesn't have `CALL` syntax. How to call the SP depends on whether it is selectable (has a `SUSPEND` statement in it's body) or not. To call selectable SP you use `SELECT` statement:

```
select outParam1, outParam2 from mySP(:inParam1, :inParam2)
```

The selectable SP returns resultset which can be treated as one resulting from an "ordianary" select statement.

To call non-selectable SP you use `EXECUTE PROCEDURE`:

```
EXECUTE PROCEDURE mySP(:inParam1, :inParam2) RETURNING_VALUES(:out1, :out2)
```

Comment: And how can you hande the parameters? Do I have to define them a special way? Or do I have to insert:
    select outParam1 from mySP($parameter1,$parameter2);

Comment: How can you define the parameters then? Can you give a full example.. I don't know how to handle the :out1 (for example)

Comment: Thats the PHP/PDO issue I'm not too familiar with (I don't use PHP too much these days)... I suggest you ask new question with specific example of the SP signature, which PDO you use etc...