# Firebird procedure is not performed only in PDO

Tags: php, stored-procedures, pdo, firebird

I have a *Firebird* procedure:

```
CREATE OR ALTER procedure INSERT_LABELS_SET (
    IN_NAME varchar(50))
returns (
    OUT_ID smallint)
as
begin
    IF ((SELECT COUNT(*) FROM labels_sets WHERE name=:in_name) = 0) THEN
    INSERT INTO labels_sets(name) VALUES (:in_name) RETURNING id into :out_id;
suspend;
end
```

When I try to execute it in PHP:

```
/**
 * @var $stmt PDOStatement
 */
$stmt = $this->db->prepare('EXECUTE PROCEDURE insert_labels_set(?);');
$stmt->execute(array($value));
```

I get an error:

**SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: -804 Dynamic SQL Error SQL error code
= -804 Incorrect values within SQLDA structure**

How can I fix the error?

Such problem is only in PDO. When I use ibase_connect() everything works perfectly.

Comment: never used firebird, but shouldn't your parameter vars inside the `begin` block be `@in_name` and `@out_id` instead?

Comment: Does this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19709935/call-stored-procedure-firebird-database-with-php-pdo

Comment: It doesn't help. Such error occurs only when I use PDO

Comment: Did you bind the param before the execute ? $stmt->bindParam(1, 'label', PDO::PARAM_STR);

Comment: Yes, I tried. Doesn't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution:

```
$stmt = $this->db->prepare('SELECT OUT_ID from insert_labels_set(?);');
$stmt->execute(array($value));
```

But why didn't work the previous version, I don't understand